# How can i update my Bot status after a new Channel was Created?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Hello iv made a Ticket Bot and i wanted to make a Counter for the Tickets but when a new ticket gets Created the counter doesn't go up!? **and i dont know how to do it so i need you Guys.**

```
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Connected to bot: {bot.user.name}')
    print(f'Bot ID: {bot.user.id}')
    category = bot.get_channel(966773969355165746)
    await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.watching, name=f'Tickets: {len(category.text_channels)}'))
```

Comment: Can you edit the code for the commands you used for making tickets into the question?

Answer (score 0):

on_ready only goes off when the bot is turned on and ready. Use `on_guild_channel_create(channel)` or `on_private_channel_create(channel)`.